# Way to get MOSS User Profile custom property Choice List to dynamically update?

Tags: user-profile, profile-sync, user-profile-property, 2007

I have been asked to determine if there is a way to get the "Choice List" that is available as an option in a Custom User Profile property to automatically update from a SharePoint list (which would be created as part of a separate process coming from a ZTable) rather than manually uploading a csv or adding the choices individually.

I had planned on using the BDC to create the connection and update using the profile import, but it is a MOSS Standard environment and going to Enterprise isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

You could attach a custom `Microsoft.SharePoint.SPItemEventReceiver` to the list and have it update the choices.

Initialize the `UserProfileManager`, call `UserProfileManager.Properties.GetPropertyByName` method to get the property, and then modify the choices via `Property.ChoiceList`. Remember to keep `Property.MaximumShown` up-to-date, and call `Property.Commit` when done.